# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am trying to create user login and registration using node express and mongoose...
created the User Model....trying now to add a post method in my router auth.js
but for some reason i keep getting the error 
**Cannot read property 'name' of undefined**
yesterday i wrote exactly the same code, but with some other post methods and it went perfectly fine....

i just want the post to work on postman for now that's it...thanks alot

[auth.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8g4f.jpg)

[User.js File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB8s5.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3oVE.jpg)

Comment: your `req.body` is `undefined` whether you have used `bodyparser` in your server.js file?

Comment: hi ...already included my index.js in the question just now....i used the app.use(express.json());      and     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

Answer (score 5):

it turned out that the order of the middleware counts here...i just moved the app.use(express.json()) before the routes add ,,,,and it went fine....thanks Subburaj...appreciate your help :)